# IIS and concurrent requests

Tags: iis, concurrency, request

I am going to host an C# Web Service in IIS 7. The traffic of this application could be a bit huge, almost 100 requests per minute.

The question is how many request can IIS served simultaneously ?

Thank you

Comment: 100 requests per minute is tiny

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Do you know what is the  maximum value of simultaneously request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your server, IIS can handle up to 100 threads per processor.
Here's a reference for you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/biztalk/technical-guides/optimizing-iis-performance?redirectedfrom=MSDN.

I would also say that what appears to be a single request to a website could actually generate 100s of requests for stylesheets, images etc. So it is almost impossible to predict what server you'd need to service this. However 100 requests per minute is a tiny load for IIS, so there is no need to worry about it. In fact my laptop could service that many page requests resulting in 1,000s of requests along with SQL server and all the other stuff I have running on it.

Comment: Thank you. This application doesn't have any interface, just a webservice with 2 operations.

Comment: Then IIS will be absolutely fine with a very basic server. I think you have no need to worry at all.